# Changing the location of a folder without affecting the path(s) stored in the database

Tags: asp.net, database, virtual, directory

I have a folder that stores images and the paths to the images are stored in the database.  There are almost 2500+ employee images stored there.

If I want to change the physical location of the folder that has the images, how do I manage the stored paths in the DB  and the virtual path, root and all the related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is what I would do:

1. Copy your images to the new directory. (Leave the old directory in place for now)
2. Run a SQL update script on your DB to change the stored location. (Without knowing your db structure I can't say more.)
3. Update your app code to point to the new directory.
4. Test your app to verify that is uses the new directory.
5. Rename the old directory to something else, so that any link to it would break.
6. See if anything is broken, and fix it!

Comment: what about the virtual directory path ?

Comment: The virtual directory shouldn't be that big of a deal. The whole idea of a virtual directory is that it looks like a normal directory to the outside world. If you need to change it, change it, and incorporate the new directory into your app and database. If you don't need to change it, well, don't worry about it.